# rsyslog - how to send multipline messages using JSON template

Tags: rsyslog

I am shipping laravel logs using the rsyslog imfile module. 
I use the startmsg.regex to deal with multiline messages. These work great.

```
input(type="imfile"
      File="laravel.log"
      Tag="laravel_app"
      startmsg.regex="[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2} [[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2}"
)
```

I then ship the logs out to **Logstash** (and then use them in **Elasticsearch**, and Kibana)
I ship the logs using a **Rsyslog template**

```
template(name="json-template"
type="list") {
constant(value="{")
constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"") property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
constant(value="\",\"message\":\"") property(name="msg" format="json")
constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"") property(name="hostname")
constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"") property(name="syslogseverity-text")
constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"") property(name="syslogfacility-text")
constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"") property(name="procid")
constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

My logs look like this, where line-breaks are marked with \n

> [2018-06-07 11:02:33] testing.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Deal'
>   not found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Deal' not found at
>   /app/Http/Controllers/TestingSyslogController.php:13)\n[stacktrace]\n#0
>   [internal function]:
>   App\Http\Controllers\TestingSyslogController->index()\n#1
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('index', Array)\n#3
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212):
>   Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
>   Object(App\Http\Controllers\TestingSyslogController), 'index')\n#4
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()\n#5

So the entire message is in a single line {message}

How can I use the rsyslog template to split the message at '\n' into different objects to look something like this...
{message line 1},{message line 2},{message line x}